# Write access in mounted volume in docker

Tags: windows, docker

I mounted a folder in docker ubuntu container

```
docker  run -it --rm -v ${pwd}:/files ubuntu /bin/bash
```

but when i try to write to mounted folder get error

```
root@0974e91f50ec:/files# cat >a.txt
bash: a.txt: Permission denied
```

Is it possible to write to mounted folder?

Comment: Can you post which ownership/permission this folder has by running `ls -l` on this folder on the host?

Comment: root@0974e91f50ec:/files# ls -l  >>>>
total 1>>>
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4 Jun 12 05:31 a.txt

Comment: Seems the file is owned by root and you have read/write permission. Can you also check the parent folder with `ls -l` to see if there's correct permission to the `files` folder. Also is there a `t` missing in the `a.xt` ?

Comment: Is it possible to write to mounted folder in docker container ? @thushv89

Comment: That should be a problem as long as you have the correct permission.

Comment: how to mount it with WRITE permisssions...

Comment: You can't set permission while mounting. What I meant by "you have to have correct permission" is, if the folder `files` is owned by `root` has `rwx` access, when you mount that folder to a container and login as `root` you should be able to write.

Comment: Folder permission :- drwxrwxrwx   2 root root 4096 Jun 12 05:31 files

Comment: I am assuming you are running these commands on the host (i.e. not the container)? And according to the above comment you already have an `a.txt` file in there, which means at some point you successfully wrote to this directory?

Comment: @thushv89 even if i try to create  a new file in mounted folder using cat  it gives error...the file a.txt was created by me in mounted folder in windows  ..and i am using  command directly >>docker  run -it --rm -v ${pwd}:/files ubuntu /bin/bash

Comment: could you run this command >>docker  run -it --rm -v ${pwd}:/files ubuntu /bin/bash>>>and then cd into that direactory and try to create file or mkdir :creaet directory ...you will  same error ...now how to overcome that error

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your example. Here's what I ran on my windows machine.
[image]

And the file appears fine.

[image]

Also they appear fine in the host system (I created b.txt on the host to check if it appears fine in the container).

[image]

**PS**: Something you have to beware of is that on Windows you can only mount very specific directories (e.g. `~/Documents` directory) at least when using `Docker toolbox` (Not sure about `Docker Desktop CE`). I think to mount folders from other directories there's bit of work to be done. So it might be a good idea to make sure that whatever you are trying to mount is in fact something allowed by your Docker on Windows.

Comment: for me >>>> root@4778f72a51d7:/files# mkdir dd>>>>>
mkdir: cannot create directory 'dd': Permission denied